# Wordpress: readers changing between light and dark theme

Tags: css, wordpress

Hi I would like to create a button that allows readers to switch between light (default) and dark theme modes on my wordpress.org website.  I already created a button shortcode and the desired csscode i want for my dark theme using simple css plugin but have no idea how to relate them together.

I'm very new to wordpress and therefore have no idea how to do so. Would appreciate a lot if someone can provide a detailed walkthrough on how to implement it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We really need more information... If the light/dark CSS is managed just by adding a class to the `body` or some high level container, you can just target the button with a click event in javascript and change the body class or whatever else needs to be changed.

Also note this isn't really WordPress specific, it's more a generalized javascript or CSS question.

Here's some vanilla javascript to get you started:

```js
document.getElementById("my-button").onclick = function () {
    var container = document.getElementById("themeable");
    
    if( container.classList.contains("dark") ){
        container.classList.remove("dark");
    } else {
        container.classList.add("dark");
    }
};
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px -10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.dark {
  background: #323138;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="themeable">
 I have two themes!
 
 <a href="#" id="my-button">Change Theme</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with just using a js event listener for toggling a classname is that you will probably experience light flash of unstyled content when you refresh the page in dark mode. In 2020, there is an excellent plugin to add night mode switch in WordPress. Check [WP Night Mode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-night-mode/) plugin. If you are looking for a custom solution without plugins, I would recommend reading the following article as well: [Switching off the lights - Adding Dark Mode to WordPress](https://yonkov.github.io/post/add-dark-mode-toggle-button-to-wordpress/).